# What does a hex nut say about the age of a butcher block?

Tags: butcher-block, history, hardware

I just bought an old, thick butcher block (~16”) that has loosened up over the years and I can’t determine how old it is.  It does have ~5/8” through rods that have washers and hex nuts on them.

I feel like since it has hex nuts it probably isn’t much older than the 50s or so, but that’s just a gut feeling.

When did hex head nuts become common in furniture?  Is this evidence of the age or is it just too hard to tell from that one data point?  Aside from an obvious mark, what other clues might I look for?

Comment: I think you're likely dead-on in your guess about how old it *might* be, but you'll never know as it's possible they were replaced at some point in the block's history (the original ones, if there were original ones, having rusted enough that someone felt they needed to be removed). Edit: as to a clue to the age of the current rods, washers and nuts, are all of them zinc plated, bare steel or black finished?

Comment: @Graphus From the one plug I removed, the rod and nuts are pretty rusty, but I believe they were zinc plated based on the pattern of the rust.  I can post a picture later tonight, but thanks for the comment.

Comment: I found a lot of patents for hex-head wrenches data around 1850, so it's safe to say that hex bolts have been around for 150+ years.

Comment: @StephenMeschke, right the "hex head" existed for a long time, but in my refinishing experience, most furniture used square head nuts/bolts for a long time.  Well into the 1940's-50's.  Square head nuts usually point to a vintage piece.  You find something like a square nail and you know its even older.  What I'm not sure of is if hex heads were used sooner on larger, higher torque bolts like a butcher block.

Comment: @StephenMeschke I was surprised to find that hex nuts were much older than I supposed when I went Googling, seeing fairly widespread use long before the first war (although commonly used alongside square-headed bolts). But both my reading of old woodworking handbooks and firsthand observations suggest that they weren't ubiquitous until after WW2, which makes 50s or so a good early guess. It is of course possible they're earlier, and the finish on the nuts can help point to that (as well as their exact shaping) but galvanising most certainly points to a later date rather than an earlier one.

Comment: @Graphus I agree that checking hardware for galvanizing (discovered by Sir Humphrey Davy in 1829) is a better indication of age than the nut's shape. I have been searching for a nut dating guide, but have been unable to find one online. I'd like some general guidelines for determining the time period that a nut or bolt was produced.

Comment: I'm a dolt, I forgot to ask about the wood -_- Can you ID the species? And how clear are the rings in the end grain? If you can make them out wider spacing throughout can also point to a later date, while very tight ring spacing suggests an earlier date it's not an absolute indicator as old wood can be used later on. The glue could possibly tell you the most now that I think about it! If you can clearly identify PVA then you pretty much know.

Comment: @Graphus, Thanks again for the comments.  I don't want to be a poster that doesn't give any updates.  I will look at that and the metal and post info/pictures when I can.